# Need to use ForEach loop in csv data set config using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to login with different users each time, So I have created CSV data set config but my code is picking only the first user always from CSV file, So I used `ForEach` loop controller to pick different user from second time.
For every login it should pick the users sequentially from the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Replace ForEach Controller with [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and everything should start working as expected (alternative option is remove ForEach Controller and set Loops on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) level)

ForEach controller is designed to iterate through JMeter Variables, it isn't applicable for CSV files.

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) for reference configuration.